# wrap text image not working with responsive display

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/kC9SPK2e7iy5OYhKpwOO?p=preview

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="m-2 ml-4" style="color: whitesmoke;">
    <div class="row text-justify">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center row ml-2">
          <h1>About me</h1>
        </div>
        <article class="row single-post no-gutters">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="image-wrapper float-right pr-3">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" style="width:50%; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: -10px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="single-post-content-wrapper" style="text-align-last:right; padding-top: 5px;">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pharetra nisi sed nisi tempor, non suscipit libero dictum. Vivamus gravida cursus malesuada. Pellentesque mi nulla, pharetra ut quam sed, lobortis rhoncus lectus. Cras vel augue mi. Aliquam
              vulputate dictum ex, sollicitudin tincidunt purus venenatis sed. Donec bibendum ligula eu justo auctor, ac efficitur tortor sodales. Quisque sit amet facilisis neque, sit amet volutpat velit. Sed sagittis mattis enim, vel tincidunt dui gravida
              tincidunt. Donec imperdiet sem vitae sagittis lobortis. Pellentesque semper gravida massa. Suspendisse congue ac orci ut dapibus.
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

At line 21 I am loading an image, if I set this image to a set pixel distance, it wraps like it should. But I need to use a percentage so that the image does not disappear on smaller screens. What do I need to do to get this to work like it should work responsively?

Edit: I was trying to get this working in plunker running in this page, I have no idea how to make that happen...

Update: I used view-width instead of % and that seems to work, however this does constrain the component to the page and not its parent...

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code I think it helps you. and you should use valid bootstrap classes.

```
html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
      .hd-titile{color:#111;}
      .pro-img{width:200px;height:200px;margin: 21px 0px;}
      .pro-img img{width:100%;}
      .dis-txt{color:#111;}
      @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
      .pro-img {width:100%;height:auto;}
      .hd-titile h1{font-size: 25px;margin: 15px 0px 0px;}
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="" style="color:whitesmoke;">
      <div class="text-justify">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="hd-titile">
               <h1>About me</h1>
            </div>
            <article class="single-post no-gutters">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="image-wrapper pro-img">
                     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
                  </div>
                  <div class="single-post-content-wrapper dis-txt">
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pharetra nisi sed nisi tempor, non suscipit libero dictum. Vivamus gravida cursus malesuada. Pellentesque mi nulla, pharetra ut quam sed, lobortis rhoncus lectus. Cras vel augue mi. Aliquam
                     vulputate dictum ex, sollicitudin tincidunt purus venenatis sed. Donec bibendum ligula eu justo auctor, ac efficitur tortor sodales. Quisque sit amet facilisis neque, sit amet volutpat velit. Sed sagittis mattis enim, vel tincidunt dui gravida
                     tincidunt. Donec imperdiet sem vitae sagittis lobortis. Pellentesque semper gravida massa. Suspendisse congue ac orci ut dapibus.
                  </div>
               </div>
            </article>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've taken this code and put it in the plunker to see the result and compare the code, but it does not seem to wrap at all with your code.